# How to get a file size (and other attributes) in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

How do we get file attributes ? I primarily am looking to get the size, but also its last access time and other attributes.

I only found `(file-length some-file)` that gets a stream so is used this way:

```
(with-open-file (file "some file name") 
  (file-length file))
```

Looks to be doing the job but:

- it gets a stream: this is uncoherent with the rest of the api
- there really are no shorter function ??
- (is it the most efficient way to do ?)

I see nothing related to a file length or attributes in [Osicat](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/osicat/). Maybe is it its role and I'll fill a feature request ?

[Practical CL](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html) talks about file-length and refers to Osicat and that's it.

No more info on the [CL cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/), no more "posix" or "file" related material on the [awesome-cl](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl) list.

I would appreciate something [like in elisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html).

thanks

*edit*: maybe on [iolib](https://github.com/sionescu/iolib/blob/) but it looks like [its online doc](https://common-lisp.net/project/iolib/manual/iolib.html) is uncomplete and not talking about files even though it announces to having "a pathname library and file-system utilities". But apparently it does not have do what I'm looking for: https://github.com/sionescu/iolib/blob/master/src/os/os-unix.lisp

Comment: The Cookbook has been updated to show Osicat, file-attributes and sb-posix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Osicat](https://github.com/osicat/osicat), you call `stat` on the file and you get a bunch of things in a structure:

```
(describe (osicat-posix:stat #P"/tmp/file"))

#<OSICAT-POSIX:STAT {1004F20C93}>
  [standard-object]

Slots with :INSTANCE allocation:
  DEV      = 2065
  INO      = 7349974
  MODE     = 33204
  NLINK    = 1
  UID      = 1000
  GID      = 1000
  RDEV     = 0
  SIZE     = 4304
  BLKSIZE  = 4096
  BLOCKS   = 16
  ATIME    = 1497626097
  MTIME    = 1497347216
  CTIME    = 1497347216
; No value
```

You can access the different slots with the following functions :

```
osicat-posix:stat-dev
osicat-posix:stat-gid                        
osicat-posix:stat-ino                        
osicat-posix:stat-uid                        
osicat-posix:stat-mode                       
osicat-posix:stat-rdev                       
osicat-posix:stat-size                       
osicat-posix:stat-atime                      
osicat-posix:stat-ctime                      
osicat-posix:stat-mtime                      
osicat-posix:stat-nlink                      
osicat-posix:stat-blocks                     
osicat-posix:stat-blksize
```

Comment: Great, so there is. But is it in the doc ? I can't see it. I can't either use it: `(osicat:stat` does not exist (no tab completion or "the symbol STAT is not external…") and `(osicat::stat myfile)` is the reverse: completion ok but on enter "the function osicat::stat is undefined" :/

Comment: One might as well make a couple doc-related PRs now…

Comment: @Ehvince Thanks for the correction, this was indeed the wrong package

Answer (score 2):

Came looking for this post a few times, so here's my little update — there is now a package literally called [file-attributes](https://quickdocs.org/file-attributes).

The actual package name is `org.shirakumo.file-attributes`. It does exactly what you'd expect. Something to note: it doesn't, in fact, provide a "cleaner" way to get file size, so standard's `file-length` will have to suffice.

But if you wanted to get the creation time of a file, there is a function `org.shirakumo.file-attributes:creation-time`.

```
* (org.shirakumo.file-attributes:creation-time "test/a.txt"))
3894004708
```

Or if you're interested in modification time:

```
* (org.shirakumo.file-attributes:modification-time #p"test/a.txt")
3894004888
```

In case you need an overview of all of the file's attributes, you can do this:

```
* (org.shirakumo.file-attributes:decode-attributes
    (org.shirakumo.file-attributes:attributes #p"test/a.txt"))
(:READ-ONLY NIL :HIDDEN NIL :SYSTEM-FILE NIL :DIRECTORY NIL :ARCHIVED T :DEVICE
 NIL :NORMAL NIL :TEMPORARY NIL :SPARSE NIL :LINK NIL :COMPRESSED NIL :OFFLINE
 NIL :NOT-INDEXED NIL :ENCRYPTED NIL :INTEGRITY NIL :VIRTUAL NIL :NO-SCRUB NIL
 :RECALL NIL)
```

There are actually quite a few useful function to deal with file attributes. You may take a look at the full list in the [documentation](https://quickref.common-lisp.net/file-attributes.html#Function-index).

osicat failed to compile on my machine a few times, so I was in search of alternatives, and there it was.